# How to style in C?

Tags: c++, c, coding-style

In the internet there is CSS, how is this working in C, and C++?

For example how can I create a `red box with 200px width and height`?

Comment: `printf("red box with 200px width and height");`

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information.

Comment: This question only got closed because the _answers_ got silly.  The question is perfectly valid.

Comment: @joni [Don't mock the OP](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTMiHqlQCow#t=2m28s)

Comment: @bobobobo I agree with you, I dont really understand why they closed it :\

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing in the ISO standards for these languages to deliver this sort of functionality. The I/O model is a pretty basic text-only one.

*Platforms* such as Windows or X or Gnome or KDE will generally provide this sort of functionality as part of their libraries since that's what they're meant for.

Answer (score 6):

Neither language specifies a GUI... you have to choose a 3rd-party library and use whatever facilities it provides.  For example, Gtk or Qt.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer, there isn't.

To create a red box as you have asked, you would use some kind of graphical API.  On windows, this would be the GDI and you'd use `Rectangle`, after creating a pen (with a red colour).

There are cross-platform libraries (such as Qt) to deal with doing this on multiple platforms.

Answer (score 2):

C/C++ is a programming language which comes without most of the stuff you would expect from HTML/CSS/JavaScript. This is because it's not a high-level language like VisualBasic or Java. And it's not made to create layouts or user interfaces. It's a plain programming language to make your computer do stuff.

To create a user interface, you need use a GUI framework. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit) has a nice list of frameworks you could use.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can [bring an HTML renderer into your C++ program](http://webkit.org/) ([see Gecko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_(layout_engine)) as well.)

Needless to say, this is a bit hard.  Most of the time if you are programming using Windows or whatever, [a richtext formatted box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) will serve this purpose for you.

You're going to have a lot of trouble styling output that you are streaming to the console, beyond

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+    HELLO  WORLD!!           +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

because most consoles are not equipped with the ability to change the font from one character to the next etc.

Answer (score 1):

As far as C is concerned, you don't necessarily even have a monitor in the first place. You require platform-specific libraries for anything like this. You are, more or less, directly telling the computer (not a web browser) what to do, and the language's definition of "computer" is deliberately very broad.